Есть на стороннем сервере есть xml-файл. Он открывается лишь через view-source:https://[site.ru]/rss.xml в браузере. Как его прочитать кодом?
Он открывается лишь через view-source:https://[site.ru]/rss.xml в браузере по ссылке из кода сайта. Но не как обычно все xml, открывая окно "сохранить".
И он не считывается через:
file_get_contents();

и через:
curl_init();

Тоже не читается.
Пробовал другие xml, на других ресурсах, они сразу читаются и при указании в браузере открывают окно на скачивание. Т.е. как и должно быть. А этот при указании абсолютного адреса в браузере выдаёт следующую ошибку:

Если его открыть в браузере через view source code со страницы сайта, то можно выделить его структуру ctrl+a и сохранить к себе на FTP, как xml и тогда он(точнее вручную созданный файл) начинает работать.
Связывался с поставщиком данных rss-каналов, но он молчит.
Хочу спрограммировать что-то читающее структуру этого файла и пересохранять себе на ftp (сам механизм у меня уже есть и считывает, и сохраняет (при нормальных файлах), а вот именно те файлы, того поставщика-rss ни как забрать не могу).
Есть у кого опыт?
Альтернатив данных rss-каналов нет. Поэтому нужны именно они.

Не воспроизводится

в описании корневого элемента не хватает xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru", в документации он указан https://dzen.ru/help/news/ru/export-content/export#rss-elements
